# animation is not exporting to glb/gltf

Tags: animation, export, gltf

I'm using blender 2.93 and I'm trying to export a cat with animation to treejs.

basically, it's a low poly cat with an armature, and a short animation on its tail.
I have tried to export the cat to glb and gltf but the animations are always blank.

I tried different things but nothing works... 
I think the armature is ok.
 I changed the name of the action in the NLA tracks.
 I also tried to bake it and play with the exporting setting.

I'm new to blender and would appreciate any response that might give me an idea of what I am missing.

I have uploaded the file here-
https://pasteall.org/blend/965a1f1763a34e49a51452d727a330e8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the export window, tick "Always Sample Animation", seems to solve this.

[image]

Also note you didn't apply modifiers, you will only get half a cat wiggling half a tail.

Comment: I already tried that option, it must have been off because I played with the settings.. anyway I applied the modifiers and tried again (with that option) - still no luck

Comment: did you make sure to select both your armature and object? because you have "Only Selected" ticked as well. edit: the animation IS exported as seen in Windows 3D viewer. the problem is probably in your integration with ThreeJS.

Comment: I didn't know you could use Windows 3D viewer like that and I can see the animation now- thank you! I spent days blaming blender but apparently, the problem was actually treejs... though I have no idea why.

Comment: I have experimented with threejs. feel free to ask a new question ;)

Comment: You need to use the animation mixer in 3js.  Something like this mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( gltf.scene );
  gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {mixer.clipAction(clip).play(); });